# Computer lost power, and restarted with all the programs open

Tags: windows, shutdown, hibernate

I had a power outage recently while I had a few programs open. When I turned it back on, all the programs were still open. It was an actual power loss, and I don't have hibernate enabled on the computer. The computer was in sleep mode. How is it possible for a computer that didn't hibernate to restart with all the programs open? BTW I have windows 10.

Comment: Did windows perhaps remember which programs were running and just restartet them all?

Comment: Unlikely, since even the command prompt started up with the same history and programs running, plus I've never had this happen before

Comment: "The computer was in sleep mode" - Is it a laptop with a battery?

Comment: Nope, desktop without a ups backup. The power was out for ~18 hours.

Comment: Well then there are only two possibilities. Either the computer still had power somehow or it hibernated. Did you try to replicate this? Put it into sleep mode again and then pull the plug for a few minutes to see what happens?

Comment: Look at the System event log. Are any events logged during the 18 hour power outage? If not, what events are logged when the computer was started after the power outage? In particular, look at events written by the following Event Sources: `EventLog`, `Kernel-Power`, and `Power-Troubleshooter`.

Comment: I forgot about the event log. It appears that the computer woke from sleep about 20 min before the power outage. The boot type was `0x2` (not sure what the means). The computer says that it resumed from low power state, which is confusing me to death. I actually had a hard power outage, and I switched the power strip that my computer is plugged into off to prevent a power surge from damaging it. How it resumed from a low power state (which the log says it wasn't in sleep mode) is really weird.

Comment: You say it resumed from sleep 20 minutes  *before* the power outage. Is that before the power went out? Or before the power came back on? What about the 18 hour period during the outage and afterward? What's in the event log for that period?

Comment: Before the power went out. Nothing occurred during the 18 hours. Like I said this is a desktop without a ups supply. It was totally off.